# Colour curves tool for "value" channel

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

I'm trying to write a program to read [GIMP curves files](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-curves.html) and apply them to an image.  I have successfully implemented the curves for the red, green and blue channels, but I can't get it working for the value pseudochannel.

For the colour channels I just create a lookup table from the curves, and iterate through the pixels doing something like:

```
red = redlookup[red]
green = greenlookup[green]
blue = bluelookup[blue]
```

Good so far, I get exactly the same results in my program and GIMP.

In the GIMP page linked above, it is claimed that the value channel is defined as `v = max(r, g, b)` but I don't understand how to adjust each colour channel from looking up this value.  I'm currently knee deep in GIMP source code but it is quite convoluted.

**In summary:** if I have an array `valuelookup` representing the curve for the value pseudochannel, how can I use it to adjust the RGB values for each pixel in an image?

---

GIMP defines the channels as follows:

**Value**

> The curve represents the Value, i.e. the brightness of pixels as you can see them in the composite image.

**Red; Green; Blue**

> The curve represents the quantity of color in each of the three RGB channels. Here, dark means little of the color. Light means a lot of the color.

The values range from 0 to 255.

Comment: Welcome to Programmers.StackExchange.  I voted to move your question to StackOverflow, as I just don't see how a specific technical question about one program is at all a general programming topic.

Comment: Sorry.  I've never quite been sure of the difference of these two sites, but my logic was that algorithm type questions belong here.  I guess the question could have been a lot more generically phrased as well.

Comment: Algorithms are, but you should include some more background on the data structure instead of just a link.  From your post, I don't even know how many bits are in each channel, or if GIMP stores them as integers or HTML-esque hexidecimal.  Re-wording may help find an answer.

Comment: @DougM - I disagree regarding the close vote; I don't believe this belongs on SO. The question is about algorithms which is on-topic for here.  I agree that some additional background information would increase the chances of getting the OP's question answered.